# Raspberry Pi Raspbian Web Kiosk Virtual Keyboard Solution

Tags: raspberry-pi, touchscreen, kiosk, raspbian, kiosk-mode

I followed Alan D. Moore's step-by-step guide to have my Raspberry Pi running in kiosk mode.

I did my own configuration as I needed it to run on a touchscreen with no physical keyboard and mouse.

Here's how my ~/.xinitrc file looks.

```
xset s off
xset -dpms
matchbox-window-manager &
matchbox-keyboard &
while true; do
    rsync -qr --delete --exclude='.Xauthority' /opt/kiosk/ $HOME/
    midori -i 600 -e Fullscreen -e Navigationbar -a http://myport.ac.uk
done
```

I used apt-get install for the matchbox-keyboard to be used as an on-screen virtual keyboard solution.

Just look at how small the keys are! Barely touchable and super inaccurate... [image: example]

The real question is if anyone knows of a way to make the keyboard bigger, could recommend other solutions or tweak the config? I am a total debian newbie so I really hope I get some help here. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here: http://mottie.github.io/Keyboard/

You can make an OSK with javascript.

Comment: Awesome solution for web applications!

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace the line:

```
matchbox-keyboard &
```

with:

```
matchbox-keyboard -s 20 &
```

where *-s*  is the font size (letter) that appears on each key.